# Inconvertible types in android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android Programming and I am trying to create a multiplication app in Android Studio to help kids learn basic multiplication tables using fragments.  I am getting the following error.

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 
'com.example.multiplication_with_fragments.FragmentTwo'
```

I have not been taught all that much about the topic of fragments and I have been following along with code from an example in class. The error is being thrown in the first line of the onButtonClick method in the code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentOne.ToolbarListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(int userAnswer, int correctAnswer)
    {
        FragmentTwo fragment = (FragmentTwo) 
             getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

        fragment.displayMessage(userAnswer, correctAnswer);
    }
```

After fixing the error in the above code, the program will not run.  There is a fatal exception when I try to run the program and the program will not display on the device.

```
16363-16363/com.example.multiplication_with_fragments 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

at com.example.multiplication_with_fragments.MainActivity.
onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
```

line 12 is shown below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

If there is any more explanation needed or if more code is needed let me know and I will post it.

Comment: Now when I am running the program, it does not even open on the device.  It instantly stops and tells me there was a fatal exception with the line   
                                                                            
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Please add the error logcat to your question..

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
FragmentTwo fragment = (FragmentTwo)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

**with**

```
FragmentTwo fragment = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your fragment version should V1 and your getFragmentManager() is V4 it is miss matched.

you fragment version should be as below.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    public class MyBaseFragment extends Fragment {

        public ... {
           needs Fragment  v4 Fragment
                ....

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in FragmentTwo you have imported this type of Fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

So remove above line and import below type of Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```